# which function is used to indicate that particular script line is executed in Qtp using VB scripting

Tags: qtp

which function is used to indicate that particular script line is executed in Qtp using VB scripting.

Comment: Might be an April 1st question. it does not even contain a question mark...

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the script line number is not exposed to the script.